# Dynamic frontpage image changes every hour

Tags: 7, views, media, nodes

I want to have a frontpage with images changing every hour. As it is the frontpage, the page is cached.
Can this be done with views?
I'm thinking of creating a views block which shows a random image but I'm lost on the refresh every hour part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of views, over in its cache settings, you can choose TIME and then select one hour for the results and output. Then, if you have it show a random image, it will cache that and only select another image after that hour has passed.  This of course will be defeated if your page is cached, but if its cache lifetime is less than an hour, it will cache up eventually (I just made a pun lol)

Comment: Now, if you want the image to change "on the hour" that'll take some more finagling.

Comment: I knew it would be something that easy, thx. (I'll leave the on the hour part unspoken) :-)